# Angular4 use tab when change router,how to save edit's input data?

Tags: angular, tabs, router

angular4 tab routing switch how to keep editing and operation, the need for back-end rendering to get?When I click another tab back to the previous tab, the edited content can not be saved.

Comment: Use ngDestory() method

Answer (score 0):

Your content can be saved if you use a service in your HTML.

Or you can ask for the user to validate that he wants to leave with the `CanDeactivate` implementation.

I can provide both examples, but if you don't like neither of these solutions ... No need to !

Comment: I want to allow users to leave at any time and save editorial records, for example, I fill in half of the form, I would like to click on another tab to query statistics.